# Integration of $\frac{e^{\cos^2x}+\ln(1+x)}{10^{x^3}\arctan(\sqrt{x})}$, possibly numerical

Tags: calculus, integration

A couple of days ago I came across the following integral: $$\int_{0.02}^{0.08} \frac{e^{\cos^2x}+\ln(1+x)}{10^{x^3}\arctan(\sqrt{x})}\,{\rm d}x$$

The funny thing is, I found this integral written in a door of a bathroom stall in my university. I did what any reasonable person would do: I took a picture of the integral and tried to solve it later. Needless to say, I couldn't do it. Sure, there is a high chance of the person who wrote this being just a troll. However, I put this in [Wolfram Alpha and it gave $0.791523$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+0.02+to+0.08+%28e%5E%28cos%C2%B2x%29%2Bln%281%2Bx%29%29%2F%2810%5E%28x%5E3%29arctan%28sqrt%28x%29%29%29+dx) as the answer. Such a neat rational number.

And I wonder: is there a straightforward way to attack this? If you want to use numerical methods, fine, as long it is possible to do it by hand.

Comment: Rather looks like an approximation to me.

Comment: I don't know. Usually WA gives the result with thousands (sic) of decimals.

Comment: more digits: 0.79152271188278812399

Comment: Just replace the bounds of integration to something else and you'll see that it is just as "rational."

Comment: Fair enough. I don't know why suddenly WA decided to approximate it.

Comment: A truly kick-your-ass integral!  People often get creative in the stalls . . . see for example the story of Martin Luther and the "privy in the tower", a (to my mind) rather shoddy re-telling is here:  http://www.mostholyfamilymonastery.com/luther_denominations.pdf.

Comment: "“These [demons] would haunt the imagination of Martin Luther who had visions, which he
believed to be actual physical occurrences, of the devil hurling [excrement] at him and his
hurling it back. Indeed, in one of his many anal combats with the devil – in which Luther
would challenge the devil to ‘lick’ his posterior – Luther thought the best tactic might be to
‘throw him into my anus, where he belongs.’” (H.W. Crocker, Triumph, Roseville, CA:
Prima Publishing, 2001, p. 237.) "

I lost it here hahahaha

Comment: It *does* give me some laughs too!  Sigmund Freud loved this kind of thing, I suspect!

Comment: It is exceptionally easy to write down a difficult integral; indeed, the challenge is really to write down an easy one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments: The integral is not the number you claim it to be and W|A only gave you an approximation. In all likelihood, the integral is in fact nonsense and we have no reason to expect a nice closed form or any result that is not at the very least irrational.